# Two different classes binding to same listview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I have ItemsSource on ListView set to class Mail. I want to have one column with property from other class. How to bind that column to other class? I checked other answers, but didnt fint suitable one.

And XAML is sth im learning, so code-behind is what is use the most in WPF.

Code:

```
public class Mail
{
    [Key]
    public int IDMail { get; set; }
    public string prop1{ get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime prop3{ get; set; }
    public Sender senderID{ get; set; }      
}

public class Sender
{
    [Key]
    public int IDSender { get; set; }
    public string propSender1{ get; set; }
    public string propSender2{ get; set; }  
}
```

XAML:

```
 <ListView x:Name="listView_knjizenaPosta" Background="#FFDEDEDE" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="293" Margin="0,69,0,260" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="1018" FontSize="16" SelectionChanged="listView_knjizenaPosta_SelectionChanged" FontFamily="Verdana" MouseDoubleClick="listView_knjizenaPosta_MouseDoubleClick">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IDMail}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Prop1" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding prop1}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Prop3" Width="185" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding prop3, StringFormat=dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}" />                       
                    <GridViewColumn Header="PropSender2" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding WHAT GOES HERE?}" />

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: I think your answer lies over here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141952/wpf-nested-objects-databinding

look if you have Sender object included

Comment: Change "{Binding WHAT GOES HERE?}" to "{Binding Path=senderID.propSender2}"